# Multipass preprocessor in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cl.exe

I have code:

```
#define __IGNORE__(...)
#define XUJ(x) ); if (x) { test2(); } __IGNORE__(0

void test2() {

}

void test() {

}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    test(XUJ(x));
    return 0;
}
```

GCC compiles, but cl.exe has error:

```
$ cl 1.cpp
1.cpp(14): error C2059: syntax error: ;
```

But... if i unpack macros to:

```
test(); if (x) { test2(); } __IGNORE__(0);
```

It compiles normaly. 
MSVC 2015 compiler dont support multipass preprocessor? O_O

upd:
hm.... where braces? o_O

```
$ cl /E 1.cpp

1.cpp
#line 1 "1.cpp"



    void test2() {

    }

    void test() {

    }

    int main() {
        int x = 0;
        test(); if (x) { test2(); } ;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ensure you have the latest updates for your compiler. Also test with VS2017, and if one or both repeat the failure, submit a bug report on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. The question might not be well written and contain way to many smilies but the problem is clearly recognizable and OP even provided a MCVE.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its strange MSVC bug -_-

I move 0 to macros - bug fixed -_-

```
#define KEEEK 0
#define __IGNORE__(...)
#define XUJ(x) ); if (x) { test2(); } __IGNORE__(KEEEK

void test2() {

}

void test() {

}

int main() {
    int p = 0;
    test(XUJ(p));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a bug. The rules for macro expansion aren't intuitively obvious, but it's been too long since I worked through it to provide an answer.

Comment: Just removing the `0` works as well and doesn't require another `#define`

Comment: Or adding an extra pair of parenthesis around it: `#define XUJ(x)  ); if (x) { test2(); } __IGNORE__((0)`